# How can my plugin get notified of anterior or posterior comments (and more) changes to an IDA database?

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, idapro-sdk

IDA Pro allows plugins to receive notifications for a number of events. These are defined in the `hook_type_t` enumeration inside `loader.hpp` in the SDK from what I saw. If I subscribe to `HT_IDB` events, I have a host of options for notifications I can subscribe to (`event_code_t` in `idp.hpp`).

Now, if I wanted to patch up [collabREate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/collabreate/) by Chris Eagle to support anterior and posterior comments - how would I go about that?

colleabREate is a very useful piece of software, but in real collaboration scenarios these issues turn out to be real shortcomings.

**In short: how can I receive notifications to events in my plugin which Hex-Rays doesn't make available through the SDK as of yet?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [IDA 6.4 news](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/6.4/index.shtml):

```
+ SDK: added extra_cmt_changed IDB event for the anterior/posterior comment changes;
 also renamed the SDK functions related to these comments
```

Comment: would be good to add the terms "anterior" and "posterior" to the comment inside the `idp.hpp`. "extra comment" wasn't exactly what came to mind when grepping the SDK code :)

Comment: any idea about the other events that affect how things get displayed as mentioned in my question?

Answer (score 1):

I have written a plugin like this myself.  As far as I know, this is impossible to do within the SDK.  It is simply the case that some events do not trigger notifications and hence can not be responded to.  This is not the fault of collabREate, but rather, a built-in limitation of IDA.

Comment: I realize this isn't the fault of collabREate, Igor pointed out they newly added at least one of the functions I asked about to IDA 6.4. I guess RCE is required for the rest. IDA's license allows it, after all.